# How to load a specific view controller in KIF tests?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest, kif, kif-framework

Currently, am navigating through all view controller to reach a specific view controller for testing. But is there a way that I can load a specific view controller for testing that particular page?

Comment: Storyboard, XIB, or programmatic?

Comment: @JonReid , Hey thanks for the response. I'm one of your followers on QualityCoding. (Back to the topic) I know it can be done using all those methods you described. But I just wanted to know, is there any KIF functions that can help in loading specific view controllers.